# problem with instance of string var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a loop and on each iteration i'm setting a string var called content, this var i'm using to create some infoWindows of google map markers. But on each iteration that change the value of the var instead that make a new instance, this modifed the value and always sets the infoWindows of the markers with the last value of the var `content` why i'm doing wrong.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info[i].split(',')[5],
                                        info[i].split(',')[6]),
            optimized: false,
            map: map,
            zoom: 6,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });


        var content = '<p>Central: ' + info[i].split(',')[1] + '</p>';

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content:  content
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoWindow.open(map, this);
            currentMarker = this;
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you fix the indenting? its quite confusing.

Comment: Where's the closing `}` of your for loop?

Comment: Are you missing the closing brace for the `for`?

Comment: @Dogbert and @Daniel A. White my code it's already modified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infoWindow.open(map, this);
    currentMarker = this;
});
```

Is creating a closure and `infoWindow` points to the the outer function variable so all your handlers open the same `infoWindow`. There is only function scope in javascript(no one for every for, if, etc). Use a closure to achieve what you want:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(infoW){
    return function () {
        infoW.open(map, this);
        currentMarker = this;
    };
})(infoWindow));
```

Comment: awesome men!! i didn't know that i'm going to read a little bit more of javascript work

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed weird.

Did you try to make the content building inline?

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:  '<p>Central: ' + info[i].split(',')[1] + '</p>'
});
```

Comment: sure, that was my first solution but with the same result